# How can I use viewmodel inside a viewmodel in kotlin compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I wrote a code that saves the token after the user logs in and skips the start screen if the token is produced and goes directly to the home screen. I thought I should do this in the init function of the viewmodel to go directly to the home screen because if I do it in the ui, normally the ui is loaded at first and the screen appears, then it goes to the home screen, but I want it to go directly to the init function, so I want to do it in the init function of the viewmodel. I thought it would be true. However, when I inject the token manager view model into the start screen viewmodel, the following error appears.

actually I don't think this is exactly best solution, so how correct is it to use another viewmodel inside the viewmodel? If it is not a best practice method, how can I do this as the best solution?

> [dagger.hilt.android.processor.internal.viewmodel.ViewModelValidationPlugin]
> Injection of an @HiltViewModel class is prohibited since it does not create a ViewModel instance correctly.
> Access the ViewModel via the Android APIs (e.g. ViewModelProvider) instead.
> Injected ViewModel:

**hear is my start screen viewmodel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class StartScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val tokenViewModel: TokenViewModel
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _viewState = MutableStateFlow(StartScreenViewState.initial)
    var viewState = _viewState.asStateFlow()

    var tokenState by mutableStateOf<String?>(null)
        private set

    init {
        getToken()
    }

  
    private fun getToken() {

        if(tokenViewModel.token.value != null){
            _viewState.update {
                it.copy(
                    shouldNavigate = true
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

data class StartScreenViewState(
    var shouldNavigate:Boolean
) {
    companion object {
        val initial = StartScreenViewState(
            shouldNavigate = false
        )
    }
}
```

**start screen**

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = state, block = {
        if(state.shouldNavigate){
            navController.navigate(BOTTOM_BAR_ROUTE)
        }
    })
```

**token viewmodel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class TokenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val tokenManager: TokenManager
) : ViewModel() {


    private val _token = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
    val token:StateFlow<String?> = _token.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            tokenManager.getToken().collect {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    _token.value = it
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun saveToken(token:String){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            tokenManager.saveToken(token)
        }
    }

    fun deleteToken(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            tokenManager.deleteToken()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not use a VM inside a another VM .. you can use 2 VM separately or you can just add the Repository/method in same view model if u want to use just one .

Answer (score 2):

You can't put one viewmodel into another. Use your `TokenManager` instead:

```
class StartScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val tokenManager: TokenManager
) : ViewModel() {

...
    private fun getToken() {
        val theToken = tokenManager.getToken()
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I understand but what is the problem of using viewmodel inside viewmodel ? can you explain little bit

Comment: The purpose of ViewModel is to connect your UI with the business logic. The proper way to achieve what you need is to actually create a Manager or Repository (same thing) which fetch the data. Init this manager in your ViewModel and let it pass the decision to the UI itself.

Comment: As the your error states, ViewModels can't just be created(What would happen if you inject it into another) They need to be created using a viewmodel provider, since they are cached in the viewmodel store. Best is to read the viewmodel documentation about it: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel